# Unable to add multiple variable subscription products in WooCommerce in Cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

*FYI - The below mentioned process works perfectly fine on localhost (local env) but not on our server.*

I'm developing a feature called "Home Try On" where we are allowing the customers to buy two pairs of shoes at the same time at the cost of one, but if customer fails to return the product then we would be deducting the cost of the other product using Recurring Payment Method. So, to ease out the process we purchased "WooCommerce Subscriptions" but it's not allowing the customers to add multiple products.

Here is an example scenario of actual work flow - We have kept all the Home Try On products as Variable Subscription products

- Customer visits the website
- Customer goes to Home Try On Section if he/she is unsure of their shoe size
- Customer selects on Product let's say it as X Product and selects one pair (Size 6) and adds to cart, now we want the customer to add another pair of X Product (Size 7) but the problem is it's now allowing to add multiple variable subscription products and throws an error "A subscription has been removed from your cart. Due to payment gateway restrictions, different subscription products can not be purchased at the same time."

Can someone help me out on this? We purchased the WooCommerce Subscription plugin because it mentioned multiple subscriptions are accepted. It stated:

> Your customers can also purchase different subscription products in
>   the same transaction and Subscriptions will group the products to
>   reduce the payment gateway fees and logistical overhead for their
>   future renewals.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction please?

Regards,
Piyush

Comment: Welcome to the SO community however this question is not about programming at all so has been flagged as *off topic*. Consider using the support channels available for WooCommerce or the plugin provider.

Comment: If you have purchased the Subscription plugin you should try WooCommerce support. Also your "A subscription has been removed from your cart. Due to payment gateway restrictions, different subscription products can not be purchased at the same time." would indicate that you need to find a payment gateway processor that supports multiple subscriptions.

Comment: This is clearly off-topic but this may help. [Multiple subscriptions](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/multiple-subscriptions/)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that finds this question:

You haven't activated stripe yet. As the subscriptions plugin needs stripe  woocommerce needs to have stripe activated!

it is free. just go to [stripe](http://stripe.com) and create an account. there you get two keys that you can use on your side.

hope this helps someone

Comment: I still get the message with stripe activated. Any idea why?